# Error while saving syntax, and JSON.parse code

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
let cofig = require('./botconfig.json');
let token = config.token;
let prefix = config.prefix;

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Запустился бот ${bot.user.username}`);
});

bot.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        msg.reply('Pong!');
    }
});

bot.login(token);`
```

My bot is supposed to answer by `Pong!` when I type the `ping` in a channel. It's a simple ping test to check if the bot is alive and behave correctly. However I have an error when I try to make it work.

Error:

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\mrakp\OneDrive\Рабочийстол\mamapapads\botconfig.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:801:27)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mrakp\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\mamapapads\bot.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
```

Comment: Can you add your JSON files?  Especially `botconfig.json`

Answer (score -1):

Well first off, you can't do 
`const cofig = require("./botconfig.json")`

Then not use the declaration in order to get the token.
In your case, bot.login(token) would actually be bot.login(cofig.token)

But you can also do

```js
const { token } = require("./botconfig.json")

//Rest of code

bot.login(token)
```

Which would get the token directly, instead of having to use a declaration in order to reference it.

Comment: OP is already declaring `token` as `config.token`. The destructuring assignment is a good suggestion but doesn't solve the issue. The error is originating from parsing the JSON file (which hasn't been shared with us), so any `require()` statement using the file would throw the same error.